# Length of a module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let R be a commutative ring, M an R-module of finite length and let N be an Injective R-module with zero socle. Then why $ \text{Hom}_R(M, N) $ is zero?

Comment: How does this question arise in your research?

Comment: In a paper of Auslander(Isolated singularities and existence of AR sequences) What can be said if M and N are in R-mod. 

Answer (score 3):

if some hom is non-zero, then the image is a module of finite length, which allows to find 
an irreducible submodule in $N$ giving a contradiction.